Fold a .diff file by file in VSCode
In VSCode, if I examine a .diff file, output from git diff, I'd like to be able to fold by which file the differences are in. Apparently in "diff" mode this is not the default.
So concretely, one solution would be a folding rule that a folding region starts with the string diff --git and ends with the same or with EOF.
Suggestions involving extensions for intelligently interacting with output of git diff are welcome also, if they include how to fold by file.
